# what's the difference between resize and reshape?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
IMG_SIZE = 50
resized_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
reshaped_array = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

Doesn't both lines of code reveal the same thing?

its just that when I removed one line of code among them my model isn't working.

Comment: `resize` can scale an image up or down.  `reshape` is an array operation that can add dimensions as needed for your model (here 2d to 4d), but cannot change the total number of array elements.  They are very different operations and shouldn't be confused.

Comment: After a reshape you will still have the same number of elements in your array, just in a dfifferent shape. After a resize, you will likely have a different number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize can increase or decrease the size of the image. For example, you can resize image from 100x100 to 20x20.
Reshape changes the shape of the image without changing the total size. For example, you can reshape image from 100x100 to 10x1000 or to 1x100x100.

Comment: good intuitive explanation,but one more doubt, when i removed the resized_layer in the the model didnt worked? is it because the fact that every image should be same size?

Comment: Yes. Usually, models receive images of the same size.